# Most efficient way to receive json async responses?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

(my case applies to C#, MVC, returning JSON, got jquery, angular), but I expect it applies to more than that.

I have a website where my angular/html/js calls ~7 services through Angular controllers and async-gets/displays data (weather, road conditions, etc). Some of these take longer than others (from ms to ~10s). I'd like to have a single call to my service which returns all of this data - but doesn't wait until the last call to return anything (10s).

Is there a way to make a single call, and return results as I have them and they get displayed accordingly?  Do I need to have a repeating call which has a boolean like "IsMore=T" and calls the service again? (doesn't sound efficient).

Ideally, I'd like to keep a response channel open and keeping pumping results until it's done. Possible?

Comment: Do you currently make 7 HTTP requests and you only want to make a single request?

Comment: yes (to my services) - but I want to do it without waiting until I have the last data ~10s before displaying the first

Comment: If you make seven asynchronous requests to your server the server can process all seven requests in parallel and return each response as it becomes available. It's down to your client to react to each response as it arrives. If you make one request then the server issues one response which could well not happen until all the processing is complete. Your server code _could_ break a request into seven threads and process it, but that's unnecessarily complicating the server code and client code. I'd stick with seven requests unless you can show that the network latency is problematic.

Comment: I agree with Hobo Sapiens based on what you've described, but if you do need a server to client channel take a look at SignalR - http://signalr.net/.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand completely, but I think you could just chain the  response promises together, something like:

```
$scope.getWeatherData = function () {
  return myWeatherService.get().then(function (resp) {
    $scope.weatherData = resp;   
  });
}

$scope.getTrafficData = function () { 
  return myTrafficService.get().then(function (resp) {
    $scope.trafficData = resp;
  });
}

$scope.getWeatherData.then(getTrafficData).then(...chain others...);
```

This assumes that the service calls return a `$http` promise.

Anyway, whenever the promise comes in, the data will be on `$scope`, and hence the display will be updating as the promises arrive. It sounds like you might be using something like `$q.all()`, which would wait until all promises are resolved.

Comment: thanks, it's more of the opposite of that - where I wanted one call (to optimize calls) which return whatever comes in first immediately, then whatever second comes in, to the last, without having to wait for the last thing to display the first thing. Also, they may have different orders, so chaining wouldn't work that way either (even IF it worked oppositely).

Hobo Sapiens reply may work - I haven't found a network loss (it's on Azure so it's SOLID), however I have thousands of clients, refreshing often (cached, but still). Likely good as is.

Answer (score 0):

Buildilng on @reptilicus' answer:

```
$scope.getWeatherData = function () {
  return myWeatherService.get().then(function (resp) {
    $scope.weatherData = resp;   
  });
};

$scope.getTrafficData = function () { 
  return myTrafficService.get().then(function (resp) {
    $scope.trafficData = resp;
  });
};

$q.all([
  $scope.getWeatherData(), 
  $scope.getTrafficData()
]).then(function () {
 // do whatever's next, or nothing
});
```

... would request/receive both responses in parallel (if that's what you want).  The relevant $scope property for each request will be populated when the related response is received, and the "do whatever's next" code will run once they are all complete.

Note, you need to inject $q to your controller constructor for this to work. :)

Edit: I just noticed that @reptilicus did mention $q.all. The difference between chaining the `.then`s and $q.all is that under chaining, one request wouldn't start until the previous was received....